# Find and Replace to add text to end of cell data

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is is possible to do a find/replace on all cells within a calendar style worksheet that start with a consistent text, then has varying text or digits, to add additional text onto the end of the string? Eg: I am starting with TID #620 and would like to add (awx) to the end to display as TID #620 (awx). However, the #620 could be any variation of any three digit number, or 3 character text (TID #NAN, or TID #451). There is also the potential there could be additional text (TID #620 (BELL ONLY)) where I would still want it to display as TID #620 (BELL ONLY) (awx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's Find and Replace is not flexible enough to do what you want: While you can Find all the strings in the sheet that begin with TID, there's no way to tell Replace to put in "(awx)" at the end of the strings that are found.

However, you can use formulas in combination with Copy/Paste Special to achieve the same result.

The idea is to add a set of formulas that make the replacement you want for the cells that begin with "TID", and just replicate the content of the rest of the cells.  Then, you would copy the range with the set of formulas and then paste it *as values* over the original data range. Finally, you would delete the set of formulas that you added.

Something like the following formula should work for you (it assumes the data begins in cell A2).

```
  =IF(LEN(A2)=0,"",IF(LEFT(A2,3)="TID",A2&" (awx)",A2))
```

The logic of the formula is straightforward:

- If the data cell is empty (i.e., the length of its contents is 0), return an empty string.
- Otherwise, if the first three characters of the cell's contents begin with "TID", return the cell's with " (awx)" added at the end.
- Otherwise, just return the contents of the cell.

[image]

Comment: Why overcomplicate? `=IF(LEFT(A2,3)="TID", A2&" (awx)", A2)` is enough.